# JDK1.7 ClassLoader Memory Leak

Tags: java, memory-leaks, classloader

I have child-first UrlClassLoader to load jar file dynamically. Then I do a reflection to invoke a method within loaded jar file. Once it is finished, I prefer to unload the classloader. Then I try to do some stress test code to make sure my code run smoothly. Basically, what I try to do is load and unload jar within looping statement. Here is my code:

```
    for (int i = 0; i < 1000; i++) {
        //Just to show the progress
        System.out.println("LOAD NUMBER : " + i);

        ChildFirstURLClassLoader classLoader = null;
        try {
            File file = new File("C:\\library.jar");
            String classToLoad = "com.test.MyClass";
            URL jarUrl = new URL("file:" + file.getAbsolutePath());

            classLoader = new ChildFirstURLClassLoader(new URL[] {jarUrl}, null);
            Class<?> loadedClass = classLoader.loadClass(classToLoad);
            Method method = loadedClass.getDeclaredMethod("execute",
                    new Class[] {});

            ClassLoader currCl= Thread.currentThread().getContextClassLoader();
            Thread.currentThread().setContextClassLoader(classLoader);
            method.invoke(null);
            Thread.currentThread().setContextClassLoader(currCl);

            method = null;
            loadedClass = null;
        } finally {
            if (classLoader != null) {
                classLoader.close();
                classLoader = null;
            }
        }
    }
```

When I'm running this code under JDK1.6, without `classLoader.close();` statement, that code runs perfectly. But when I turn into JDK1.7, sometimes I get `java.lang.OutOfMemoryError: PermGen space` error. Unfortunately it occurs in inconsistent manner.

Comment: You could try setting the maximum perm gen to see if this happens more often with lower values.  You can also check that the maximum is the same for Java 6 when this doesn't happen.

Comment: What does your com.test.MyClass class do? There was a change in Java 7 so that pending finalize methods can block the class from being deallocated, maybe that is the issue you are seeing here. Create a heap dump on OutOfMemory, load it to MemoryAnalyzer (or a similar tool), list class loaders and search references to them.

Comment: Thank u Peter and Mihi , I have tried to increase max permgen, but it is still the same. In Java 6, I run only with 64m permgen space without problem. Actually, com.test.MyClass is querying into database by using Spring JDBC. I have already analyzed my heap dump and I saw there are no strong references into classloader. Thanks all.

Comment: what happens if you use a URLClassLoader instead? still OOME?

Comment: Which ChildFirstURLClassLoader are you using here?  The typical reason for this kind of error is a memory leak in the class loader.

Comment: I have found my solution. Once I added clearCache to Java Bean Inspector, the leak was gone. GC can collect dead ChildFirstClassLoader objects. Thanks all.

Comment: what you mean? i have same problem how resolve you? thanks

Answer (score 2):

The easiest way to confirm where the leak comes from is to use a profiler to monitor the memory usage. Try JProfiler, or VisualVM. It will enable you to pinpoint the exact location of the leak, and also give you clues as to whether and how you can fix it.